# How to scrape mobile phones from a website

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape the list of mobile phones links from vivo website from the below URL

URL https://www.vivo.com/in/support/system-update

However, I am only able to scrape the "Hot Models" in this context and not others

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_page_links(url):
    baseurl='https://www.vivo.com'
    r=requests.get(url)
    sp=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    links=sp.select('li.box-model-item a')
    return [baseurl + link.attrs['href'] for link in links]



def phone_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data = {
        "Release_Date": sp.select_one('.no-flip-over:-soup-contains("Release date") + span').text,
        "Downloads": sp.select_one('.no-flip-over:-soup-contains("Downloads") + span').text,
    }
    return data


def main():
    urls=get_page_links('https://www.vivo.com/in/support/system-update')
    results=[phone_data(url) for url in urls]
    return results



df=pd.DataFrame(main())
df.to_csv("oppophones.csv", index=False)
print("Saved to CSV")
```

can you please tell me how do I print other model phones?

Answer (score 0):

Because this URL contains only hot models
https://www.vivo.com/in/support/system-update

Try this link:
https://www.vivo.com/in/products?choose=all

Comment: Sir, I am trying to scrape the release date and number of downloads from this URL 

https://www.vivo.com/in/support/system-update and I want to do it for all the other models as well

Comment: yes i understand but you can only scrap info which is available at that page or else the owner of the page did have  some secured environment that is why u can not access all . so use other URL or find another way for ethical hacking. :)